# Plausibility notwithstanding and Otherwise?

Tags: meaning-in-context, postpositive-adjectives

I looked up the dictionary but these two terms are very difficult to get. could any body clarify on me?

> **Plausibility notwithstanding**, rumors about unwitting folks engaged in **otherwise** low-risk activities contracting HIV have circulated for decades. Similar versions involved a booby-trapped gas pump, deliberately tainted ketchup dispensers, and adulterated pizza purposefully contaminated with infected bodily fluids.

Source:[snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/politics/medical/hivoranges.asp)

Answer (score 2):

***Plausibility notwithstanding***
It's not surprising that this confuses you: it involves both an unusual construction, an over-casual ellipsis, and at least one misuse.

- *Notwithstanding*= “despite” acts here as a *postpositive preposition*—that is, as a preposition which stands *after* its complement.<sup>†</sup> Its object is *plausibility* = “believability”. The preposition phrase may be paraphrased

  > Despite believability
- *X notwithstanding* often occurs at the beginning of a sentence to designate some factor which has been overlooked or bypassed or overcome in the action of the main clause, something which you might expect to have prevented the action:

  > His grief notwithstanding, Herbert kept going to work after his son's tragic death.

  Ordinarily, however, the noun *X* is ‘defined’ with a determiner or modifiers  to make its semantic and syntactic relationship to the action clearer. In the sentence above, for instance, *his* marks *grief* as Herbert's grief, not general community grief. In your example, this definition is omitted, so it is not very clear what *plausibility* is involved. What the author probably means is:

  > Their plausibility notwithstanding, rumours . . . have circulated for decades.
- But that makes no sense at all—why should believeability prevent rumors from circulating? One of two things has happened here: either the author has mistakenly written *plausibility* when he meant ***im**plausibility*, or he has misunderstood *notwithstanding* to mean something like *regardless*. *Notwithstanding* is not a common word, and almost never occurs in speech, so I think the second mistake is more likely; the author probably means:

  > Rumors . . . have circulated for decades without anyone stopping to consider whether they were plausible.

***otherwise***
*Otherwise* here is an adverb meaning “in other respects”; it modifies the adjectival phrase *low-risk*

> otherwise low-risk activities = *activities which in other respects carry little risk (but happen to incur severe risk with respect to infection)*

---

<sub>Other prepositions which may be postposed are *apart* and *aside*; *ago* is always postposed.</sub>

Comment: I never thought I'd find myself accusing *you* of being "pedantic"! It's interesting to note that OED's most recent citation is (*The Observer*, 20 Sept. 10/1/1987, *The anxieties of Nato notwithstanding, it is difficult to see how the West can fail to benefit*) clearly uses the qualifier the same as OP's example. That's to say ***even ignoring** issues relating to Nato's anxieties*, it's difficult. You seem to be stuck on the idea that *notwithstanding* should only be used in contexts where it effectively means ***despite***, but I don't think that's how most people see it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 1) I think you've miscounted the hedges in your citation: the author says "Despite NATO's anxieties, the West will benefit."  2) That notwithstanding, your paraphrase with *even* incorporates precisely the "concessive" sense that is missing from OP's example.

Comment: +1 Just as a side note: *Ago* is postponed by tradition only. It doesn't have to be.

Comment: @pazzo W e l l . . . Exactly the same might be said of every "rule" of English morphology and syntax and pragmatics :)

Comment: Ooops - you're quite right that I didn't correctly net down all the hedges and negations in the OED example. But I still can't see how OP's example differs from [*it was obvious that, mere legality notwithstanding, the conquerors simply refused to acknowledge the conquered as vested with rights they were in any way bound to respect*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sRf8_S1st9IC&pg=PA39&dq=%22legality+notwithstanding%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QGFXVfbrDurD7gaf24LICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22legality%20notwithstanding%22&f=false). Which I read as *ignoring issues of legality* (whether legal or not).

Comment: @pazzo But if we break tradition like in the example in your profile (*\*\*Ago December it snowed forty four inches in Buffalo*), we end up with a sentence that is very ungrammatical with no obvious meaning...

Comment: @snailboat I have heard, although I am not sure, that Shakespeare broke tradition quite a lot. Then there are artists in other disciplines who break tradition, and probably get quite the same reaction as the one you've given. Not every sentence has to has obvious meaning. Do you prefer: "Ago last December it snowed 44 inches?" Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @pazzo I have nothing against people writing ungrammatical or unclear sentences.  They can do it all they like.  I just wouldn't point to those examples and claim they're grammatical or meaningful.  As for your revised example, I'm afraid it's still unclear to me.  Is it supposed to mean the same thing the sentence would if you removed *ago*?  "Last December it snowed 44 inches" is fine, of course.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And I say that sentence is another instance of the same mistake. *Notwithstanding* ≠ *regardless of* or even *even regardless of*, it = *despite, in spite of*.

Comment: @Pazzo A language *is* a tradition. All we ever talk about on ELL and ELU is English tradition. The interesting thing about "ago" at the start of a sentence is that tradition could allow it (and your other intriguing examples), even if it hasn't occurred before in modern English, in the complex and peculiar way that traditions allow some unprecedented things but not others.

Comment: @BenKovitz I think I would readily understand "ago two years" as meaning "two years ago", even though it's not the order we normally use for these words.  It's only one step away from normal usage, so I think I can make a guess about the meaning (and I think it'd probably be right).  The tricky thing about pazzo's example is that not only is the order different, it's not taking the same type of complement.  I could guess that "ago December" means "December ago", but what does *that* mean?  It's at least two steps away from normal usage, and I'm not sure I can make the right guess.

Answer (score 1):

The construction ***X notwithstanding*** (and the somewhat less common sequence *notwithstanding X*) is a "qualifier" that modifies the immediately preceding or following statement/assertion within the current utterance or sentence.

Essentially it means *in the context of the associated statement, issues relating to **X** should be ignored.* So in OP's example it means the writer does not wish to explicitly express an opinion as to how plausible the rumours are (though the reader may quite reasonably infer that the writer thinks they're *not* plausible, otherwise why would he mention the issue at all?).

Adjectival/adverbial ***otherwise*** (which in this context means *in [all] other respects*) modifies ***low-risk*** activities. That's to say, activities which *are/would be considered low-risk* (if it weren't for the fact that they're associated with the transmission of AIDS).

Comment: +1 But I think it's a misuse of *notwithstanding*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you are too forgiving, too willing to find clarity in the muddle. And I'd say to the original author: How are the benign, low-risk aspects of those activities relevant to *anything*?  It's like saying "Pointing a gun and pulling the trigger (which is *otherwise* low-risk) can be dangerous when the gun is pointed at a person."  Unless the author means by *otherwise* "when engaged in by persons neither of whom is HIV-infected", in which case he is leaving something important out of the sentence.

Comment: @TRomano: Perhaps you're right. I can't deny that taken literally, *X notwithstanding, [statement S]* means ***despite** X* (i.e. - *X **does not stand** as an obstacle to the validity of S*). So ***X*** should really be something which would ordinarily be assumed to undermine S. Would you like OP's example any better if it had been ***Implausibility** notwithstanding,...?*

Comment: ... As to the *otherwise* issue, I think you're on sticky ground with your counter-example, since *pointing a gun and pulling the trigger* would ordinarily be assumed to be dangerous. But you wouldn't usually think of  gassing up the car, using ketchup, or eating pizza as anything other than low-risk things to do (the risk of *anything* going wrong is relatively low, and were it not for those [implausible] rumours, you certainly wouldn't think doing them would infect you with AIDS).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I do agree with you on the gun thing, sort of, though its analogues in the original sentence are "deliberately tainted", "booby trapped", and "adulterated".  Eating ketchup at a restaurant, *otherwise* low-risk, can seem high-risk if one fears the bottle has been adulterated.  The word "otherwise" just doesn't make sense to me there.  *normally, usually, typically*, would make better sense.  I think the author is using *otherwise* as a synonym for "normally".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Their *im*plausibility notwithstanding, rumors..."   Exactly. Or "Plausibility*aside*, rumors..."

Answer (score 0):

It's not the clearest sentence, and "otherwise" is not used properly.

Plausibility notwithstanding =  no matter how implausible it may seem

otherwise low-risk activities =  activities that would typically be considered low-risk

Comment: I can't see any reason to say it's *not the clearest sentence*. I don't deny some *learners* may find the construction more challenging than, say, *The cat sat on the mat*, but to native speakers it's perfectly ordinary English. And as to *"otherwise" is not used properly*, I think that's just plain *wrong* - it's a standard construction.

Comment: I agree with FF that *otherwise* is fine here; but I think *notwithstanding* ***is*** misused.

Comment: Shouldn't it be, *Their implausibility notwithstanding, rumors...* rather than what we have, which is a vague nod in the general direction of "issues of plausibility"?

Comment: That *plausbility* is a typo for *implausibility* is one possibility -- *plausibility*? :) . . . I incline toward the 'misuse' theory only because I see exactly this misunderstanding of *notwithstanding* as "regardless of" very often in my editorial work.

Comment: I didn't mean to say it was a typo, but that the author has his language inside-out.  The author probably meant to say, "Plausibility aside, rumors...". I agree with you on the misuse. I'm just saying that that if we keep "notwithstanding", we'd have to change "plausibility" to *im*plausibility.

Comment: We are in complete agreement on that point.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think I must have been having an off day yesterday. You're quite right that *X notwithstanding* means *despite X*, not *[even] disregarding issues concerning X*, and that the author *should* therefore have used ***implausibility*** (or as TRomano says, replace *notwithstanding* by ***aside***, though that does seems a bit flaky to me). So it seems the only remaining issue is the use of ***otherwise*** - which looks fine to me, and I'm not clear on why *anyone* would take exception to it in the cited context.